# 64/128GB microSD card that works with the Huawei Honor 7

Tags: smartphones, microsd

I am searching for a good, fast microSD card with 64GB or 128GB of storage for a reasonable price. Must be compatible with the Huawei Honor 7 smartphone.

I don't know what it is important when buying microSD cards, so I would like some advice and some specific models that are good and have a good price. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several great brands that make Micro SD cards, including, but not limited to

- SanDisk
- Lexar
- Samsung
- PNY
- Kingston

I read [here](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-microsd-card/) that Samsung and SanDisk tend to make the best micro SD cards in terms of performance, but the difference is not much to look into.

Realistically, they will all serve you well, so if you do find a really good deal on a MicroSD card, just go for it. A link to the Amazon Page for MicroSD cards is [here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_3015433011_nr_p_n_feature_two_brow_3?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A%21493964%2Cn%3A541966%2Cn%3A172456%2Cn%3A516866%2Cn%3A3015433011%2Cp_n_feature_two_browse-bin%3A6518305011&bbn=3015433011&ie=UTF8&qid=1442021432&rnid=6518301011). Just make sure you look at the reviews.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using a [SanDisk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010Q57S62) MicroSD card. They're probably one of the most popular options, and for a good reason, too. They're very reliable, and not too expensive (Especially the 64GB one; The 128GB is newer technology, so it'll cost more per GB). I've used mine for years, and never had any problems with them.

It might be tempting to buy a really cheap one from a brand/company nobody ever heard of, but I don't recommend purchasing storage devices from untrusted/unknown companies, because, in my experience, they tend to cause lots of problems, most often being data loss.

Comment: Data loss meaning, in simpler terms, fake storage capacities, so the drive pretends to be gajillions of bytes and whatnot, and then overwrites everything you give it inside of it's 2MB of storage...